# PDE with Initial Values and no solutions

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I need some help understanding PDE with initial values. The exercise ask us to find all solutions to the PDE $u_x - 2u = 0$ that satisfies the following conditions:

1. $u(0,y) = y^2$
2. $u(1,y) = y^2$
3. $u(x,1) = x^2$

My attempt is the following: I start by finding $u(x,y)$.
$$
u_x - 2u = 0 \implies \frac{u_x}{u} = 2
$$

$$
\implies \int \frac{u_x}{u}dx = \int 2dx
$$

$$
\implies u(x,y) = k(y) e^{2x}
$$

Now, for the initial conditions I substitute the $x$ and $y$ values given and would get the following :

1. $u(x,y) = k(y) e^{2x}$ and $u(0,y) = y^2 \implies k(y) = y^2$. Therefore the solution must be $u(x,y) = y^2 e^{2x}$.
2. $u(x,y) = k(y) e^{2x}$ and $u(1,y) = y^2 \implies k(y) = \frac{y^2}{e^{2}}$. Therefore the solution must be $u(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{e^{2}} e^{2x}$.
3. Has no solution.

I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, is this what I'm supposed to do? I'm not sure what the actual solution should look like.

Comment: You seem to have solved the question correctly, well done.

Answer (score 1):

Its right.

Regarding the 3rd one: the equation can be thought of as a transport equation whose characteristics (c.f.: the [method of characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=method%20of%20characteristics), wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics)) are lines parallel to the $x$ axis.

What is happening is that they asked you to put initial data right on a characteristic curve. Therefore, unless the initial data is prepared correctly, there will be no solutions.

For example, if they instead asked you for solutions solving $u(x,1)=e^{2x}$, you should be able to write down at least two different solutions (!) with the same values on the line $y=1$.